# How to make a url button for a telegram bot using java

Tags: java, button, telegram-bot

I have not that much experience with java but I'm trying to make a telegram bot.
I want to create a button which opens a link when you click on it but I don't know how.
This is my code:

```js
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.replykeyboard.InlineKeyboardMarkup;
import.org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.replykeyboard.buttons.InlineKeyboardButton;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

if (message_text.equals("test")) {
  InlineKeyboardMarkup markupInline = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();


  List < List < InlineKeyboardButton >> rowsInline = new ArrayList < > ();
  List < InlineKeyboardButton > rowInline = new ArrayList < > ();
  rowInline.add(new InlineKeyboardButton().setText("https://www.google.com/").setCallbackData("I don't know what to put in here"));
  rowsInline.add(rowInline);
  markupInline.setKeyboard(rowsInline);
  message.setReplyMarkup(markupInline);

} else if (update.hasCallbackQuery()) {
  String call_data = update.getCallbackQuery().getData();
  long message_id = update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getMessageId();
  long chat_id = update.getCallbackQuery().getMessage().getChatId();


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself:

```js
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.methods.send.SendMessage;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.Update;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.bots.TelegramLongPollingBot;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.exceptions.TelegramApiException;
import org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.replykeyboard.InlineKeyboardMarkup;
import.org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.replykeyboard.buttons.InlineKeyboardButton;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

if (message_text.equals("test")) 
    {InlineKeyboardMarkup markupInline = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
            List < List < InlineKeyboardButton >> rowsInline = new ArrayList < > ();
            List < InlineKeyboardButton > rowInline = new ArrayList < > ();
            rowInline.add(new InlineKeyboardButton().setText("Open Browser").setUrl("https://www.google.com/"));
            rowsInline.add(rowInline);
            markupInline.setKeyboard(rowsInline);
            message.setReplyMarkup(markupInline);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InlineKeyboardMarkup markupInline = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();

List < List < InlineKeyboardButton >> rowsInline = new ArrayList < > ();
List < InlineKeyboardButton > rowInline = new ArrayList < > ();

InlineKeyboardButton inlineKeyboardButton = new InlineKeyboardButton();
inlineKeyboardButton.setUrl("https://google.com");
inlineKeyboardButton.setText("Blabla")
inlineKeyboardButton.setCallbackData("Call back data");

rowInline.add(inlineKeyboardButton);

rowsInline.add(rowInline);
markupInline.setKeyboard(rowsInline);

message.setReplyMarkup(markupInline);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).